# ionic header & contents missing after build

Tags: ios, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to build a mobile app.
However emulating in browser result and build result are different like following images.

How am I supposed to fix this issue ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYzQ3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt2Cq.png

HTML

```
<ion-view view-title="More">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-list>
      <!-- Account details -->
      <ion-item class="item-divider item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
        Account management
      </ion-item>

      <!-- Show when user is already signed in -->
      <ion-item ng-if="signedIn" class="item-icon-right" href="#/tab/yellow">
        Change details
      <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item ng-if="signedIn" class="item-icon-right" href="#/tab/yellow">
        My listings
      <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item ng-if="signedIn" class="item-icon-right" ng-click="signout()">
        Sign out
      <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>

      <!-- Show when user isnt signed in -->
      <ion-item ng-if="!signedIn" class="item-icon-right" href="#/tab/account/signin">
        Sign in
      <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item ng-if="!signedIn" class="item-icon-right" href="#/tab/account/signup">
        Sign up
      <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>

      <!-- Useful tools -->
      <ion-item class="item-divider item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-cash"></i>
        Useful tools
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('tekoria.controllers.account',[])

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $window, AccountService) {
  $scope.signedIn = AccountService.current();

});
```

Service

```
angular.module('tekoria.services.account', [])

.factory('AccountService', function($rootScope) {
  Parse.initialize("removed", "removed");
  return {
    current: function() {
      return Parse.User.current();
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: use <ion-header> tag to add header.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine after I put libraries into the local folder rather than using a CDN